# Windows Mail not setting Bcc address programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I have a method that composes and shows an email in the native Windows Mail application. For some reason it is not setting the `Bcc` address field.

```
public static async Task ComposeEmail(string url)
{
    var emailMessage = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage();
    var bbcEmail = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailRecipient("myemail@gmail.com");
    emailMessage.Bcc.Add(bbcEmail);
    emailMessage.Subject = "Sending info to you";
    emailMessage.Body = "Click the link below to access some materials for your review:\n\n" + url;
    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(emailMessage);
    return;
}
```

EDIT:

`TO` and `CC` work

Comment: Does it work if you *also* specify a To:? A mail can't have only a Bcc: and no To:, so it may get filtered before the composer can show it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert having a To: and a Bcc: does not work. The Bcc: isn't populated

Comment: It may be a bug either in the app itself or in the `EmailMessage` class. Try sending a feedback using Feedback Hub.

Comment: @MarianDolinský this was our hunch. `Feedback Hub` is where I should post huh?

Comment: Well, you could look for the bug on [Windows Platform bug tracker](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/platform/bugs) or contact them as they suggest since the ability to add new bugs is STILL coming soon.  But I remember there's a `Development platform` subcategory in FBH.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. This is a known issue in our system and related team is working on this.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT Anyway to get updates on this issue? Any ETA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback. This is a known issue that has been fixed. You should be able to get this work with Mail Version 17.8400.4044 (Not released yet). For now, there is no workaround for this (you may use `CC` instead of `BCC` or suggest users to manually fill the `BCC` field in Mail), please wait for the release of the new version. Apologize for any inconvenience and thank you for your understanding.

Comment: @visc New Version 17.8400.40745.0 has released, which has fixed this issue. You can update to this version and have a try.